# Restore of db's on local locks me out of accessing other sites

Tags: mysql, restore, configuration

Running my local dev websites on my Mac locally and when I am restoring a database via terminal, which the restore is running I cannot access anything that uses mysql, I get a broken pipe notice.

Is there anyway to allow a restore without it giving me this issue when trying to work on a second, seperate site that uses a direct db but same server?

The error I get when trying to access any development site that uses mysql during a restore

```
Notice: PDO::__construct(): send of 130 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in /Library/WebServer/Documents/Sites/site_name/includes/database/database.inc on line 307
```

Not normally an issue but currently restoring a particular database that is so large it would take 40 minutes to restore.

```
Server version: 5.6.22 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Command used

```
$ mysql -u root -p itrs < clientx_web_live_200315.sql
```

My.cnf

```
# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
# basedir = .....
# datadir = .....
# port = .....
# server_id = .....
# socket = .....

# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES 

wait_timeout=3600
```

Comment: Try to raise `innodb_buffer_pool_size` as much as you can. You must balance the ram from mysql and other tools you use for development. I have assumed that you use innodb table.

Comment: Thanks. Provide this as an answer and I will vote it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using innodb tables, try to raise `innodb_buffer_pool_size` as much as you can. You must balance the ram from mysql and other tools you use for development. The idea is to don't have a swapping machine and to use memory resource as best as possible.